# Universal point position

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to know the universal coordinates of the point?

I mean the following:
we have the button which could be pressed by clicking (500;500) when application maximized;
if it possible to know which point to click to press the button when the window of application is 600x600;

And so on. Is there any function to calculate such a point?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just use the button's Click event?

Comment: @Tim S., this is application specific. It is 3d party and in testing puposes I need to know such an information.

Comment: Just to clarify, is there an existing 3rd party application and your application is to determine the location of their button when their application is moved/maximized ?

Comment: yes, @Xantix, that is exactly what my app should do.

Comment: You might be able to traverse the window tree using p/invoke Win32 API calls. FindWindow, FindWindowEx, etc.

Comment: @Digitlworld, not applicable here. For some reason, I have only Parent window and no child ones. That's why I'm trying to make a solution using coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a general function, since any developer could change the appearance based on screen size.

However, different approaches may work:

1. Somehow get a handle to the button/element of interest, then just call its clicked command, or use that handle to get the coordinate position on the screen.

   - For instance, with Web pages, you can get the specific HTMLElement by name (or id) and then work backward from there.
   - If it is a Windows Form application, you can actually get a handle onto the window of that application, and then get the desired element/component by walking through them all.
2. Create a list of the button locations under different maximization/restorings/movings and calculate the function from that. (Perhaps make a computer program to help with this).
3. As a last-resort, like for applications which randomly move their buttons around to confuse bots (I can't think of any real life examples), you might need to do image analysis on a screenshot.

The spy++ tool in/for Visual Studio has a finder tool that can help get the window/element names of windows applications.

Comment: thanks, the only approach applicable here is second one. So I'll try to do such a function and provide it if any.